# Need some help in Getting file to ouput it in the TextField by Just a press of a JButton

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, button

This is now the code i erased other that is not 
   needed can you run this now??? i do appreciate if you can run this and tell me the part          that i am wrong. This is my Project for the finals i don't know know how i will do the next and previous button. So I consulted this site especially you

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class dadas implements ActionListener {
static String summary,summary2,summary3;
JFrame frame=new JFrame("Generator X");
JPanel p = new JPanel();
JLabel studentno=new JLabel("Student No:"); 
JLabel name= new JLabel("First name:");
JLabel lastname= new JLabel("Last Name:");
JTextField number= new JTextField();
JTextField name2= new JTextField();
JTextField lastname2= new JTextField();
JButton next=new JButton("NEXT---->");
JButton prev=new JButton("<----PREV");
JButton add=new JButton("Add");
JButton save=new JButton("Save");
public static void main(String args[]) {
    new dadas();
}
public dadas(){
    frame.setSize(300,500);//frame
    frame.setLayout(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setResizable(false);

    studentno.setBounds(30,30,80,60);//LABEL
    number.setBounds(100,45,100,25);//TextField
    number.addActionListener(this);
    number.setDocument(new JTextFieldLimit(7));
    number.setEditable(false);
    name.setBounds(30,70,100,65);//LABEL
    name2.setBounds(100,90,100,28);//TextField
    name2.addActionListener(this);
    name2.setEditable(false);
    lastname.setBounds(30,115,100,65);//LABEL
    lastname2.setBounds(100,133,120,28);//TextField
    lastname2.addActionListener(this);
    lastname2.setEditable(false);
    next.setBounds(150,170,100,30);//Next Button
    next.addActionListener(this);
    prev.setBounds(50,170,100,30);//Previous Button
    prev.addActionListener(this);
    add.setBounds(50,210,100,30);
    add.addActionListener(this);
    save.setBounds(100,250,100,30);//Save Button
    save.addActionListener(this);
    frame.add(studentno);
    frame.add(name);
    frame.add(lastname);
    frame.add(number);
    frame.add(name2);
    frame.add(lastname2);
    frame.add(next);
    frame.add(prev);
    frame.add(add);
    frame.add(save);

}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
if(e.getSource()==add){

number.setEditable(true);
name2.setEditable(true);
lastname2.setEditable(true); 
next.setEnabled(false);
prev.setEnabled(false);
}
else if( e.getSource()==save ){//save button

summary = (" "+number.getText()) ;
summary2 = ("" +name2.getText()) ; 
summary3 = (" "+lastname2.getText());
String I = dadas.summary;
String Love = dadas.summary2;
String You = dadas.summary3;
try {

BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(newFile("C:\\lol.txt"),true));

bw.write(I);
bw.newLine();
bw.close();

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"Your File has been Saved");
}
catch(IOException E)
{
}
}
else if(e.getSource()==next){//Next Button 
    try {
        String filePath = "C:\\lol.txt";
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));//my file Writer
        String file;
        while((file = br.readLine()) != null){
            number.setText(file);
            lastname2.setText(file);
            name2.setText(file);
        }
        br.close();  
    }catch(IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace(); 
     }
  }
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: `" i need to know how to work this program...."` -- where did you find the source code for this program? Can you show the link? Also, please put in the small effort required to show well formatted code and not all left justified hard to read code. Also [tag:javascript] tag removed as your question has *nothing* to do with Javascript whatsoever.

Comment: What does your input file `lol.txt` look like?

Comment: Also, you want **never** want to do this: `catch(IOException F) {}`. If you don't catch exceptions, how will you know if one occurs or more important *why* it occurs. At least print the stacktrace. `catch(IOException ex) {ex.printStackTrace()}`

Comment: Byron my lol.txt is an empty file i just add it by inputting file by FileWritter

Comment: I forgot a semicolon: `catch(IOException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}`  Please address my issues.

Comment: its ok i manage it. please help me how to add codes in Next and previous button (-/|\-)

Comment: no need for (-/|\-) haha lol

Comment: Please clarify your statement above -- what have you managed? Again please address my issues since well formatted code is readable code, and it's not asking too much of you to make it easier for us to read. Also and again, what is the source of this code? Please answer these questions so that your question does not get closed.

Comment: sorry i edited my work

Comment: i manage the semicolon.that you issued. and my source code is JAVA

Comment: 1) Your code is still poorly formatted, all left justified. Your code should have proper indentation/formatting to make it easy to read. 2) when you added the `printStackTrace()` to your catch block, did you see any exceptions?

Comment: i do not see any exceptions

Comment: Of course not -- your posted code shows that you're still ignoring them.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding:

```
try
{
String filePath = "C:\\lol.txt";
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
String file;
while((file = br.readLine()) != null){
file = br.readLine();
number.setText(file);
lastname2.setText(file);
name2.setText(file);
br.close();

}
}catch(IOException F)
{
}
```

- You're still ignoring exceptions, something you should never do. Again, at least print a stack trace.
- You're reading from the file *twice* within your while loop. Only read once in the while condition.
- You're closing the BufferedReader each time you try to read *one* line. You should only close it after you've read the entire file.
- Your code is still poorly formatted making it *very* difficult to read. Please put in the small effort and so as not to make your code more difficult to read than it needs to be. This isn't asking too much of you, really.

i.e.,

```
BufferedReader br = null;
try {
  br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
  String filePath = "C:\\lol.txt";
  // String file; // bad variable name
  String line; // better name
  while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
    // file = br.readLine(); // Don't read twice

    // You'll probably want to split the line in order to extract info from it
    // not sure what your line looks like so I can't suggest a String to split on
    String[] tokens = line.split(...); // this needs to be fixed

    number.setText(tokens[0]);  // ? first token in line? not sure
    lastname2.setText(tokens[1]); // ? 2nd item in tokens array? not sure
    name2.setText(tokens[2]); // ? 3rd item in tokens array? not sure
    // br.close(); // ** no don't close the br here.
  }
}catch(IOException ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace(); // Always catch or throw your exceptions. Don't ignore them.
} finally {
  br.close();  // better to have this in a finally block actually
}
```

Comment: and  `BufferedReader br` should be declared as `local variable` or before `try - catch - + finally` block, then `br.close();` should be moved to the `finally block` (is executed in all cases), otherwise (on 1st. exception) `BufferedReader` and `FileReader` stays in JVM memory

Comment: Sorry i just Registered hours ago and this is my first Question

Comment: @ChrisYao: welcome to stackoverflow. There's still time to edit your question and post formatted code. Again, please do so without delay.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels do you run this program?

Comment: @ChrisYao: do you mean stackoverflow? hardly. Do you mean have I run the code I've posted above? Nope. You would need to create and post an [sscce](http://sscce.org) as well as a simplified text file for us to be able to do that.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels w8 i will do it now

Comment: @ChrisYao: thank you for the attempt to clean up your code.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Do you know what is the problem now?\

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels are you still there???
if your not

someone help me :(

Comment: @ChrisYao: I've posted help in my answer above. If you're still confused, then please clarify your problem by editing your original question. Tell and show more about what you've tried based on my answer above, and about how it's not working. The details are important.

Comment: ammm @HovercraftFullOfEels do you have facebook/email i want to send a pic of my problem

Comment: @Chris: I cannot publish my facebook name. Post a link to your image in your question. Post your *latest* code as an edit to your question. Clariy your question by describing your current problem in as specific a way as possible. Clarify any confusion about my answer above by asking specific questions about it.

Comment: can i post it here @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: Where can i post a Picture??

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: @ChrisYao: edit your original post and either post the picture or a link to the picture if you are unable to post the picture. Again, provide as much details about your problem as possible.

Comment: @ChrisYao: You'll want to find an image sharing site, not facebook, and upload the image there. Again, provide as much details about your problem as possible.

Comment: ok wait just a minute

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels http://s1084.beta.photobucket.com/user/Christopher_Pangilinan/media/1.png.html here is the picture.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I will sleep it is 1:27AM in the morning i will resume my questions after 10 hours but i will left you the problem how can the file reader can read the 3 lines and print it in the Text in their own Textfields Sorry my mind is too slow now

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels what will i do with the parameter? in this?String[] tokens = line.split(...);

Comment: i got it @HovercraftFullOfEels